# Problems adding Identity Management

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana, azure-bot-service, cortana-skills-kit

I'm trying to add identity management to my Cortana Channel, but when I hit save (Connect to Cortana) nothing happens. **I'm able to update the name of the bot and invocation phrase**, **but the identity management section is still empty after a save.**  I've filled out all the required fields. I've also tried adding identity management through my.knowledge.store.

**My main question is, does anyone have any recommendations on actions I can take to fix or get this resolved?**

My second question, is anyone else experiencing similar issues?

It was working great a few months ago when I built a separate bot. I was using identity management for account linking for that one too.

Comment: Do you try to check the configures information on **Authentication** blade in my.knowledge.store? Are values same as you configured on Azure portal?

Comment: I had the same issue earlier last week - all values saved under connected account got lost if you reopen the blade. I think starting from 20th it started working again. Seems like a bug they've fixed.

Comment: @patrick.ryan93, are you still running into this issue?